# Feeding images of large sizes to Fast and Faster RCNNs

Tags: python, performance, keras, object-detection

I have a large image of size 1792 x 1792 x 3 And I want to use R-CNN on it using say VGG-16 (input shape 224,224,3), I use Some region proposal algorithm, Then crop n(say 500) regions from the the large image then  resize it to 224,224,3 pass it to VGG-16 and then use a regression head and a classification head to get the desired output. But I am kinda confused in using Fast and Faster R-CNN. Both of them have this extracting the Regions Of Interest (ROI) after the image has gone through the VGG-16 (from the last pooling layer) and use ROI pooling. But I am confused how to pass the 1792 x 1792 x 3 image to VGG-16 that has a input shape of 224,224,3.

P.S:

1) rescaling the image from 1792x1792x3 to 224x224x3, I think is a bad idea because of the very high loss of image information while rescaling

2) My current idea is to add a convolution and pooling on top of VGG16 that takes in 1792 x 1792 x 3 as input and outputs a vector of 224x224x3 so that it can be fed into the network